# MonoTouch PopToViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, navigationcontroller

Does anyone have an example for `NavigationController.PopToViewContoller();` using MonoTouch/Xamarin?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward - just call the method, and pass a reference to a view controller that is already in your navigation stack.

Answer (score 5):

To go back to the last ViewController:

```
this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
```

To go to the Root View Controller

```
this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```

To go to a new viewController do this:

```
this.NavigationController.PopToViewController( MyNewViewController, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First the view controller you want to pop to, needs to be in the navigation stack, so you must have pushed to it at some point previously in navigation.

Answer (score 0):

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];